# gulp-typescript is compiling all .ts files not just those from specific location

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, gulp-typescript

I've a gulp task that's responsible for converting .ts files in a given location and spitting out .js in another given location.

The issue I'm having is that it's not only taking .ts and converting to .js from the given location, before sending to the destination, but it's also doing the same for everything in the parent and sibling folders.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
root
|__dist
|
|__source
|  |__bot
|  |__logon
```

Here's a simplified version of my gulpfile.js:

```js
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    ts = require("gulp-typescript");

var paths = {
  botScripts: 'source/bot/*.ts',
  releaseBot: 'dist/bot'
};

// Create typescript project
var tsBotProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

// Create the tasks
gulp.task('botscripts', function() {

  var tsResult = tsBotProject.src(paths.botScripts)
  .pipe(tsBotProject());

  return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.releaseBot));
});
```

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

As I said, it does transpile to .js just fine, but what I end up with is *all* of the typscript files, regardless of location, transpiled to .js and copied into the same folder structure under dist:

```
root
|__dist
|  |__bot
|  |  |__*.js
|  |__logon
|     |__*.js
|
|__source
|  |__bot
|  |__logon
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tsBotProject.src()` doesn't take any arguments. You're trying to pass it `paths.botScripts`, but that argument is simply ignored. Instead `tsBotProject.src()` emits exactly those files that you specified in your `tsconfig.json`. In your case that is everything except `node_modules`.

You have two options:

**Option 1:** You can use `tsBotProject.src()` in your `gulpfile.js` like this:

```
var tsResult = tsBotProject.src()
  .pipe(tsBotProject());
```

In order for this to work you also have to add an `include` property to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "include": [
      "source/bot/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**Option 2:** Use `gulp.src()` instead of `tsBotProject.src()` in your `gulpfile.js`:

```
var tsResult = gulp.src(paths.botScripts)
  .pipe(tsBotProject());
```

Comment: Hi Sven - thanks for the explanation. 

Taking that in mind and having looked at my gulpfile.js again, the behaviour does make sense. Using my current approach, I'd need to create a new tsproject.json file for each bunch of files I'd like to transpile - and that just doesn't make sense.

So what I've done is taken Option 2 and that works perfectly well - assuming of course that it's still respecting the settings within the tsBotProject (tsconfig.json settings)

Thanks again!